# free()ing multiple times if malloc() and realloc() was called multiple times in a loop

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Let's say I have a fragment of code that contains this

```
s = strtok_r(buffer, " \t\n", &saveptr);
do
{
  inStr = (char*)malloc(strlen(s)+1);
  (void) strncpy(inStr, s, strlen(s)+1);

  inputStrings=(char**)realloc(inputStrings,(nElems+1)*sizeof(char*));
  inputStrings[nElems] = inStr;
  nElems++;
}
while((s = strtok_r(NULL, " \t\n", &saveptr))!=NULL);
```

Will I have to free() inStr and inputStrings many times (esp for inputStrings in a for-loop up to nElems) or just once each? So far I haven't found any articles that directly addressed this so I assumed that freeing once is enough. Please do inform me if any information is lacking for this question. Thank you.

Comment: Aside: You should **not** use the pattern `ptr = realloc(ptr, size+1);`. If `realloc()` fails (which it can, just like `malloc()`) and returns NULL, then you've lost your pointer and cannot `free()` it.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist it's OK if your strategy for recovering from out-of-memory is to terminate the process and your operating system cleans up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to `free(inputStrings)` once. All the `realloc()` calls free the old block and allocate a new block.

You do need to `free(inputStrings[i])` for every value of `i` from `0` to `nElems-1`. Everything that's allocated needs to be freed eventually.

When you're done with the array, you should do:

```
for (i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
    free(inputStrings[i]);
}
free(inputStrings);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you check if I free'd both malloc and realloc correctly in the edit?

Comment: You should not `free(inStr)`. It contains a duplicate of one of the `inputStrings[i]`, so you'll free something twice.

Comment: Did you meant to do nElems-1 instead of nElems? The latter gave me a Bus Error but the former made it work.

Comment: No, I mean not to do `free(inStr)` before the `for` loop.

Comment: could you check the comment above?

Comment: At the end of the loop, `inStr` and `inputStrings[nElems-1]` contain the same pointer. So if you `free(inStr)`, then the last iteration of the `for` loop will try to free the same pointer. You're not allowed to free something that was already freed.

Answer (score 1):

No, the call to `realloc` frees the old buffer if it succeeds. You only need to do `free (inputStrings);` once after this loop.

However, before freeing that, you will need to loop over `inputStrings` and call `free` on each of the entries in it (this corresponds to the calls `inStr = malloc`... .